# A functional equation in real analysis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, functional-equations

For what function $u:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ with bounded derivative, such that $\forall p\in[0,1]$,

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}u(\frac{k}{n})=u(p)$

Could it more than linear functions?

Comment: Have you checked any other functions?

Comment: see answer below -- it seems any continous function applies this equation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A theorem of Sergei Bernstein says that if $u$ is continuous, then the  sequence of functions on the left-hand side converges *uniformly* to $u$ on $[0,1]$.  The polynomials on the left hand side are called the [Bernstein polynomials.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions)